# function in javascript check repeated word not working

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function numTimesWordRepeated() {
  const str =
    "The weather is good but if the weather is bad we realy need to brace for bad weather";
  const char = {};
  const arr = str.split(" ");

  for (let word of arr) {
    if (!char[word]) {
      char[word] = 1;
    } else {
      char[word]++;
    }
  }
}

console.log(numTimesWordRepeated());
```

Comment: welcome! what's the ask other than "does not work"? what have you tried to debug the issue?

Comment: the code works if line 1 and last two lines are deleted and i only wright console.log(char) at the end, so how do I make function work?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function so it returns `undefined` which is what is logged. `return char;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more information about your problem. Anyway you have to return something from the function otherwise it will not console log your char map. If you don't return anything in the function it returns undefined.

```
function numTimesWordRepeated() {
    const str =
        "The weather is good but if the weather is bad we realy need to brace for bad weather";
    const char = {};
    const arr = str.split(" ");

    for (let word of arr) {
        if (!char[word]) {
            char[word] = 1;
        } else {
            char[word]++;
        }
    }

    return char
}
console.log(numTimesWordRepeated());
```

Comment: Its working now, thanks a lot! I wanted to display words and with each word the times it is repeated in my string. So all good now. Sorry for the bad worded question, this was my first question with stack overflow